# how to select worksheet of workbook in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

I have written code in C# and then converting it in VB using online converter tool

**C# Code :-**

```
ExcelObj = new ExcelShet.Application();
ExcelShet.Workbook theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(filepath);
ExcelShet.Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;
ExcelShet.Worksheet worksheet = (ExcelShet.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
```

**Converted VB Code**

```
Dim ExcelObj As New ExcelShet.Application()
Dim theWorkbook As ExcelShet.Workbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
Dim sheets As ExcelShet.Sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets
Dim worksheet As ExcelShet.Worksheet = DirectCast(sheets.get_Item(1), ExcelShet.Worksheet)
```

now issue is- VB doesn't have function get_item(object index)

```
    Dim worksheet As ExcelShet.Worksheet = DirectCast(sheets.get_Item(1), ExcelShet.Worksheet)
```

does any one know how to select sheet as like I am doing in C#
or
which method I should use instead of get_item(object index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the item using `Sheets(1)` because Item is the default property.  Thus, `Sheets.Item(1)` works as well.

Comment: now its giving error for next line code
"worksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").Cells.Value"

Public member 'get_Range' on type 'Worksheet' not found

Comment: But, it sounds like you got past the Sheets(1) issue so this question is answered. Please mark it answered and create a new question.